# Safely access nested value in Immutable.js structure

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm considering introducing Immutable JS in an existing React project.  The project is littered with deeply nested references, wrapped with the `selectn` utility.

For example:

```
// returns order.id or undefined if product or order or id are undefined
if(selectn('product.order.id',this.state)) {
  //...
}
```

Is there an Immutable JS API method to check a deeply nested structure, and return either the requested property or undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example.

```
var t = Immutable.fromJS({a: { aa: { aaa: 'thing' } } });
```

I want `a.aa.aaa`.

```
t.getIn(['a','aa','aaa']);
// returns "thing"
```

What if I try to get `a.aa.bbb`?

```
t.getIn(['a', 'aa', 'bbb']);
// Returns undefined.
```

Here's the API for `getIn()`: [getIn() API](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set/getIn).